# Dafny program can't prove this binary search implementation?

Tags: dafny

We are trying to write a binary search algorithm using Dafny and it seems that Dafny doesn't prove the correctness of the program.

can someone please assist?
These are the errors we are getting:

On INV: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.Dafny VSCode

On Guard1: decreases expression might not decreaseDafny VSCode

```
predicate Sorted(q: seq<int>)
{
    forall i,j :: 0 <= i <= j < |q| ==> q[i] <= q[j] 
}

method BinarySearch(q: seq<int>, key: int) returns (j: nat)
    requires Sorted(q) && key in q
    ensures j < |q| && q[j] == key
{
    var i: nat, k: nat;
    i,j,k := Init(q,key);
    while Guard1(q,key,j)
        invariant Inv(q,key,i,j,k)
        decreases V(i,k)
    {
        if Guard2(q,key,j)
        {
            i := UpdateI(q,key,i,j,k);
        }
        else
        {
            k := UpdateK(q,key,i,j,k);
        }
        j := (i+k)/2;
    }
}

predicate Inv(q: seq<int>, key: int, i: nat, j: nat, k: nat)
{
         i <= j <= k < |q| &&
         key in q[i..k+1] 
}

predicate method Guard1(q: seq<int>, key: int, j: nat)
    requires Sorted(q) && key in q
{
     0 <= j < |q| && q[j] != key
}

method Init(q: seq<int>, key: int) returns (i: nat, j: nat, k: nat)
    requires Sorted(q) && key in q
    ensures 0 <= i <= j <= k < |q| && key in q[i..k+1]
{
    i, k := 0, |q|-1;
    j := (k+i) / 2;
}

function V(i: nat, k: nat): int 
{
    if (k > i) then k-i
    else 0
}
predicate method Guard2(q: seq<int>, key: int, j: nat)
{
    0 <= j < |q| && q[j] < key
}

method UpdateI(q: seq<int>, key: int, i0: nat, j: nat, k: nat) returns (i: nat)
    requires Guard2(q,key,j) && Inv(q,key,i0,j,k)
    ensures i0 <= i
{
    if(j < |q|-1 ){
        i:= j + 1;
    }
    else {
        i:= j;
    }
}
method UpdateK(q: seq<int>, key: int, i: nat, j: nat, k0: nat) returns (k: nat)
    requires (!Guard2(q,key,j)) && Inv(q,key,i,j,k0)
    ensures k <= k0
{
    if(j > 0){
        k:= j - 1;
    }
    else {
        k:= j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dafny verifier reasons about the calls to methods `UpdateI` and `UpdateK` only in terms of their specifications. The postcondition you have given those two methods are not strong enough to prove termination. In particular, `UpdateI(..., i, ...)` may return `i` and `UpdateK(..., k, ...)` may return `k`, in which case your loop would make no progress.

I have two more suggestions.

One is perhaps a matter of taste, but I find it simplifies expressions. Use `k` as the lowest index that's not used, rather than as the highest index that's used. So, initialize `k` to `|q|`, not to `|q|-1`. This way, each iteration of the loop looks at the `k-i` (not `k-i+1`) elements starting at index `i`. That is, it looks at `q[i..k]` (not `q[i..k+1]`).

The other is that your program is really hard to read, because you needlessly have separate functions and methods for so many things. Furthermore, those things have meaningless names, like `Guard1` and `V` and `UpdateI`. I think you'd be better off just writing those expressions and statements directly in method `BinarySearch`.

A final remark. Perhaps you will find the following episode of Verification Corner helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_tx3lk7yn4

Rustan

Comment: Hi Rusten, changing k to start with |q| instead of |q|-1 leaves me with the same errors. 
As this is part of home assignment, I must use this structure of unnecessary functions.

Would appreciate any help,